# can user manipulate select box value in browser development tools

Tags: php, jquery, html, security

Lets say I have a form with a select box. I was just wondering if the user can manipulate the values of the selectbox in web dev tools in a browser and if those manipulated values will get send as the value the user manipulated.

**Example**

*Default Select Box Values*

[image]

*Tampered Select Box Values*

[image]

In the option above will the tampered (highlighted) value get send when submitting the form?

Comment: Yes. That's why strict form validation should always be used. And make sure you're using the latest on coding techniques. IE: pdo_mysql vs msqli or the deprecated mysql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it can! Never trust ANY input given from the client side - NOT just select boxes.

It is best to verify all input is present and valid.

This can be done in PHP like so:

```
$validInputs = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '...'];

$tamperedInput = false;
if (!isset($_POST['score[0]'])) {
    $tamperedInput = true;
} else {
    $input = $_POST['score[0]'];
    if (!in_array($input, $validInputs)) {
        $tamperedInput = true;
    }
}

if ($tamperedInput) {
    echo "TAMPERED INPUT";
} else {
    echo "VALID INPUT";
}
```

As in this case, all your inputs are numbers, you can make the code simpler like so:

```
$tamperedInput = false;
if (!isset($_POST['score[0]'])) {
    $tamperedInput = true;
} else {
    $input = $_POST['score[0]'];
    if (!is_numeric($input)) {
        $tamperedInput = true;
    } else {
        $number = intval($input);
        if (!($number >= 1 && $number <= 10)) {
            $tamperedInput = true;
        }
    }
}
```

You also need to keep in mind other malicious techniques such as SQL Injection.

Have a read of this for more info:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_validation.asp

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will.

You should never trust client-input directly and always verify it.